# ¿Cuál es la precedencia de operadores en Java?

Tags: java

Malentender la precedencia de operadores en Java (y cualquier lenguaje) en una fuente de preguntas frecuentes y errores sutiles.

Código como el que sigue son difíciles de entender y depurar:

```
int a = 5, b= 10;
int c = ~b / --a << 2 > 1 || true ? a ^ 2 : b | 4 >> 2;
System.out.print(c);
```

Por esto no es curioso que la documentación oficial nos diga:

> Se recomienda que el código no dependa fundamentalmente de esta especificación. El código suele ser más claro cuando cada expresión contiene como máximo **un** efecto secundario y cuando el código no depende de qué excepción surja como consecuencia de la evaluación de las expresiones.
>   [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7)

Aún así siempre es importante recordar que esto permite que un programa funcione. Por lo tanto ¿Cuál es el orden en el que se evalúan los operadores en Java?

Answer (score 5):

La precedencia de operadores en Java es la siguiente

| Nivel | Nombre | Operador |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | Paréntesis | () |
|  | Acceso a arreglo | [] |
|  | Acceso a miembros | . |
| 15 | Post-incremento unario | ++ |
|  | Post-decremento unario | -- |
| 14 | Pre-incremento unario | ++ |
|  | Pre-decremento unario | -- |
|  | Mas unario | + |
|  | Menos unario | - |
|  | Negación lógica unaria | ! |
|  | Negación/Complemento unario | ~ |
| 13 | Conversión de tipos (cast) | () |
|  | Creación de objetos | new |
| 12 | Multiplicación | * |
|  | División | / |
|  | Módulo | % |
| 11 | Adición | + |
|  | Sustracción | - |
|  | Concatenación de strings | + |
| 10 | Despl. Bits Izq. | << |
|  | Despl. Bits Der. /Signo | >> |
|  | Despl. Bits Der. /Cero | >>> |
| 9 | Menor que | < |
|  | Menor o igual que | <= |
|  | Mayor que | > |
|  | Mayor o igual que | >= |
|  | Comparación de tipos | instanceof |
| 8 | Igual a | == |
|  | No igual a | != |
| 7 | Si binario | & |
| 6 | O exclusivo binario | ^ |
| 5 | O inclusivo binario | | |
| 4 | Si lógico | && |
| 3 | O lógico | || |
| 2 | Condicional ternario | ?: |
| 1 | Asignación | = |
|  | Suma y asignación | += |
|  | Sustracción y asignación | -= |
|  | Multiplicación y asignación | *= |
|  | División y asignación | /= |
|  | Módulo y asignación | %= |
|  | Si binario y asignación | &= |
|  | O exclusivo binario y asignación | ^= |
|  | O inclusivo binario y asignación | |= |
|  | Despl. Bits Izq. y asignación | <<= |
|  | Despl. Bits Der. /Signo y asignación | >>= |
|  | Despl. Bits Der. /Cero y asignación | >>>= |
| 0 | Flecha de expresión lambda | -> |

Comment: Buenas amigo @UselesssCat ¿Qué diferencia hay entre Más y Menos del nivel 13 respecto de Adición y Sustracción del nivel 11? Gracias.

Comment: @ValMartinez Los operadores + y - unarios del nivel 13 sirven para representar signos como +(a) o -(b) mientras que los operadores + y - binarios del nivel 11 representan sumas y restas, ej a + b, c - d.